# Defining an element in jQuery selector as optional?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to select an element through jQuery, but one of the element in the selection is optional. So I have something like this:

```
$('div.myClass span a>img')
```

In my scenario, that `a` element is an optional one. It may or may not exist in the DOM.

Of course, I can write out the entire line again with one containing `a` but this looks verbose:

```
$('div.myClass span a>img').css('opacity', 0.5);
$('div.myClass span img').css('opacity', 0.5);
```

Is it possible to define the `a` element to be optional in the jQuery selector path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need the `a >` if you want to *specifically* target *only* images within the anchor. Otherwise, `div.myClass span img` will target any image inside the span.... regardless of the presence of an anchor tag.

---

`$('div.myClass span a > img');`

```
<div class="myClass">
    <span>
        <a href="#"><img src="THIS IMAGE IS TARGETED" /></a> 
        <img src="BUT THIS IMAGE IS NOT" />
    </span>
</div>
```

---

`$('div.myClass span img');`

```
<div class="myClass">
    <span>
        <a href="#"><img src="THIS IMAGE IS TARGETED" /></a> 
        <img src="THIS IMAGE IS ALSO TARGETED" />
    </span>
</div>
```

---

`$('div.myClass span img').not('a > img');`

```
<div class="myClass">
    <span>
        <a href="#"><img src="THIS IMAGE IS ** NOT ** TARGETED" /></a> 
        <img src="THIS IMAGE IS TARGETED" />
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't make an optional element selector (other than using `*` but that's not a great idea). Instead you could combine both the selectors in to a single jQuery object, like this:

```
$('div.myClass span a>img, div.myClass span img').css('opacity', 0.5);
```

Note however that if the second selector is valid for your scenario, then the `>` selector is redundant anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a context and make your selectors behind it like:

```
$('a > img, img', 'div.myClass span').css('opacity', 0.5);
```

And in your case, you only need the `img` because `a > img` will select the same image:

```
$('img', 'div.myClass span').css('opacity', 0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use only

```
$('div.myClass span img').css('opacity', 0.5);
```

It will work as your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You could also cut the expression, and use `find`

`$('div.myClass span').find('a>img, img').css('opacity', 0.5);`